# Umbraco4: How edit a Macro in a Template?

Tags: umbraco, umbraco4

I have a Contact Page in a site made in Umbraco 4. The contact page is part of the "Contact Page" template via a Macro, as you can see in this image:

[image]

I need to update this contact form. How I can do it? I dont find how.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

If you navigate to the Developer section of the umbraco site, you should see a section called "Macros". If you select the macro in question, you should be able to find out what file you need to edit to change the macro.

Check out the image below. This is where you can go to find out which files you need to edit to change a macro:

[image]

This is where you can find the files that render the macros depending on what file type is selected in the macro in the umbraco backoffice:

- **XSLT** => /xslt
- **.NET User Control** => It should say where the file is (ex /usercontrols/DisplayError.ascx)
- **.NET Custom Control** => These controls are compiled into the specified assembly
- **script file** => /macroScripts

I'd check out umbraco.tv. They have a lot of documentation on how to get started with things like macros. If it saves you a few hours, it is worth the money.

http://umbraco.tv/videos/umbraco-v7/implementor/working-with-umbraco-data/macros/what-are-macros/

Comment: Thanks @Bowsem. I already search there and don't find how edit that Macro. About umbraco,tv and general documentation is about Umbraco 7 and the site I'm working with, is in Umbraco4.  :(

Comment: Also Umbraco.tv is a paid service. I can't access tha videos.

Comment: Were you able to navigate to the Developer section and see the Macros? I'll update my post with a screenshot of what you should be looking for. Let me know where you are getting stuck. The good news about the difference between umbraco 7 and umbraco 4 is that the way that the backoffice is organized is not very much different. You'll still see the same Content, Settings, and Developer sections with many of the same options.

Comment: Ah yeahhh!!! I found in that way the file I editd via FTP.. Perfect.. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

In Umbraco4 some Macros are in in cshtml files.
You need to go to FTP and edit the file.